# Mapping a structure to a collection in biztalk 2009

Tags: dictionary, biztalk, biztalk-2009

My Input is something like :

```
<Person>
 <FirstName>abc</FirstName>
 <Bsn>2345467</Bsn>
<Person>
```

The output should be :

```
<Person>
  <properties>
    <property>
       <propertyname> Firstname </propertyname>
       <propertyValue> abc </propertyValue>
    </property>
    <property>
       <propertyname> Bsn</propertyname>
       <propertyValue> 2345467 </propertyValue>
    </property>
   </properties>
</Person>
```

I mean the target does not have specific properties/atrributes.  Instead it has a collection of properties, wherein i specify the property's name and property's value.

Any help is highly appreciated.

I am using Biztalk 2009

Please help

Comment: I have tried, looping and table functiod, but no help. !

Answer (score 1):

I would use custom XSLT in this case- either by using the [scripting functiod](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee267841%28v=bts.10%29.aspx) or by replacing the whole map with a custom XSLT file (depending on how the rest of you map looks).

The solution could look something like this.

**XML**

```
<Persons>
 <Person>
  <FirstName>abc</FirstName>
  <Bsn>2345467</Bsn>
 </Person>
</Persons>
```

**XSLT**

```
 <xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
 <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>

 <xsl:template match="Persons">
  <Persons>
   <xsl:apply-templates select="Person" />
  </Persons>
 </xsl:template>

 <xsl:template match="Person">
  <Person>
   <properties>
    <xsl:apply-templates select="*" mode="properties" />
   </properties>
  </Person>
 </xsl:template>

 <xsl:template match="node()" mode="properties">
  <property>
   <propertyname>
    <xsl:value-of select="local-name()"/>
   </propertyname>
   <propertyvalue>
    <xsl:value-of select="."/>
   </propertyvalue>
 </property>
 </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**Result**

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
 <Persons>
  <Person>
   <properties>
    <property>
     <propertyname>FirstName</propertyname>
     <propertyvalue>abc</propertyvalue>
    </property>
    <property>
     <propertyname>Bsn</propertyname>
     <propertyvalue>2345467</propertyvalue>
    </property>
   </properties>
  </Person>
 </Persons>
```

Comment: Hi Riri,

Thanks for the response ! I could solve the above with the **Table looping functoid**. But, there came a twist when i had a more trickier target schema.

Now the target is something like this :



  [1]: http://i.imgur.com/8r5ec.png


Means the BSN was to be mapped to Integer Type of Extended Property, while FirstName to StringType Of extend property.

I couldn't achive this !

Any ideas ?